# adding infinity loading to my react app cause extract posts from database like Repetitious loop

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hello I have Problem in my mern stack app

first of all I added the limit and skip value into my backend node js like this code

```
const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  const limitValue = req.query.limit || 10;
  const skipValue = req.query.skip || 0;
  const posts = await Post.find(userId ? { bookmarks: userId } : {})
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .populate("author")
    .populate("tags")
     .limit(limitValue)
     .skip(skipValue)


  if (!posts) res.status(204).json("No posts found");
  else {
    res.status(200).json(posts.map((post) => post.toObject({ getters: true })));
  }
};
```

then I come to my react app and added the infinity scroll . but like code below

but there is one problem . it just loop the first 10 post from database instead of fetching new posts from database

this is my react code

```
const PostsList = ({  filteredTag, toInvalidate, enableImages = true }) => {
  const advertise =async () => {
    
    window?.EventBus?.emit('reset-ads')
    
  }
   useEffect(() => {
   advertise()
  }, []);









  const [posts, setArticles] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAgain = async () => {
      if (posts != null) {
        // await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?skip=10`)
        await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?skip=10")
        .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => setArticles([...posts, ...result]));
      }
    };

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const html = document.documentElement;
      const body = document.body;
      const windowheight =
        "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : html.offsetHeight;

      const docHeight = Math.max(
        body.scrollHeight,
        body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight,
        html.scrollHeight,
        html.offsetHeight
      );

      const windowBottom = windowheight + window.pageYOffset;
      if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {
        console.log("we reached the bottom");
        fetchAgain();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [posts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      // const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts`)
      const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts")
      const data = await res.json();

      setArticles(data);
      console.log(data);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);














  



  return (
    <Wrapper>
       {posts?.length > 0 ? (
        posts.map((post, i) => (
         <><><Post
            post={post}

            isFirstPost={enableImages &&  i++}
            filteredTag={filteredTag}
            key={nanoid()}
            toInvalidate={toInvalidate} />
            <Advertise />
            </></>
        ))
      ) :
      <LoadingSpinner />
      // (
        
      //   <Placeholder />
        
      // )
      }        
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

If possible some one answer me I tried every solutions . it just infinity scroll is working . but not fetching new post after first 10 post

can not understand why this happening because of the backend code or my react code not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are hardcoding the value of the skip to 10. That is why each time it calls the `fetchAgain` function, it only skip the first 10 posts. Instead of this you can use the length of the posts to get the skip value like the following code

```
const fetchAgain = async () => {
  if (posts != null) {
   let skip = posts.length;
    // await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?skip=10`)
    await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?skip=${skip}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setArticles([...posts, ...result]));
  }
};
```

To limit the posts you can use limit=10.

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because of your db query, as your query first find the result, then limit the size of result to `limit` and later on it skips the first few value of result depending on `skip` size.
Your Query should be

```
const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  const limitValue = req.query.limit || 10;
  const skipValue = req.query.skip || 0;
  const posts = await Post.find(userId ? { bookmarks: userId } : {})
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .populate("author")
    .populate("tags")
     .skip(skipValue) //this should be above
     .limit(limitValue) //after skipping
     


  if (!posts) res.status(204).json("No posts found");
  else {
    res.status(200).json(posts.map((post) => post.toObject({ getters: true })));
  }
};
```

Also, in your front-end code, this part need correction

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAgain = async () => {
      if (posts != null) {
        // await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?skip=10`)
        await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?skip=10")
        .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => setArticles([...posts, ...result]));
      }
    };
```

As it will loop through only first 10 post, because val of `skip` is fixed. Instead it should go like:

```
var skip = 10;
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAgain = async () => {
      if (posts != null) {
        // await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?skip=10`)
        await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?skip=${skip}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => { 
             setArticles([...posts, ...result]) 
             skip += 10
          });
      }
    };
```

Here `skip` is value defined above and starts with `10`. Also this code needs some more work, removing boilerplate code but to do that I will need full code.

This part is more of a recommendation,as you can improve the fetching system using `IntersectionObserver` as I also used this. To know more about it you can search on youtube there are some great videos.

Comment: it did not worked i think my react app code also not working can u check this line for me          await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?skip=10")
I add the skip=10 query to frontend code i am sure i do something wrong in my frontend part can u check please why it is loop the first 10 post . i did the things that u said . something change .now looping the first 10 posts . please check my react code if possible . thankyou very much . please

Comment: can u see my react code why this happening . i am stuck in this code for many days . please answer me if possible

Comment: the infinity scroll is lopping the first 10 post . no matter what i do what line of code i change . it just same not fetching the second 10 post

Comment: @samurai sorry i just logged back in and i'll try to help you.

Comment: @samurai edited the code for front-end, check if it works

Comment: I Tried without  limit and skip . and then the infinity scroll is not working . it just fetch all the posts from database at the same time  .  how can i use sandbox . to push all website into it ? it is not a single page . if i push to github full source code . can u run on your local envirenment and then with npm run stack website runes . it would be hard for you right ? i do not know how use sandbox

Comment: let me try new front end code

Comment: @samurai give me your repository link

Comment: please wait a few miute i try this new front end code u wrote then if it not worked i push into github as fast as possible . i do not want take your time . u so kind.

Comment: I pushed to git hub https://github.com/am0029/fallen1   backend code is into file postcontroller.js   and front end part is in postlist.jsx  with npm run stack project run sorry i had problem with pushing into github . i took your time sorry . i did not want to i am trying your code again and again but something wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252567/discussion-between-samurai-and-fallen).